# Tableau highlight Table rows width gradient color

Tags: tableau-desktop

I want to color the row colors of a table differently depending on the category.
Like this:

[image]

I couldn't do that in Tableau. Because the categories are in one field not in different fields, so that I could not use the measure field with the "create your own legend".

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the drop down in the Marks Card from Text to Square would do that. The Split Legends option would allow further customization. Adding a reference pic. [image]

[image]